# Benchmark Generator Tool

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-rec, benchmarking

Is there any tool which will provide nice graphical representation of benchmarking result. I am looking for ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you have the data and plotting is the requirement,
Check references at [**Data visualization tools for Linux**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-datavistools/)
Most of these should be available on Ubuntu

You can also try the Microsoft Excel Charts technique with
[**OpenOffice Spreadsheet Charts**](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Charts_in_Spreadsheets)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type of diagram you want to create. I like  **[gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)** for this sort of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT*** sorry I didn't finish reading the question before I posted. However the Phoronix suite does do a nice job of visualising its results for the user if i remember correctly.

## [Phoronix Test Suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/)

[image]

The Phoronix Test Suite is the most comprehensive testing and benchmarking platform available for the Linux operating system. This software is designed to effectively carry out both qualitative and quantitative benchmarks in a clean, reproducible, and easy-to-use manner. This software is based upon the extensive Linux benchmarking work and internal tools developed by Phoronix.com since 2004 along with input from leading tier-one computer hardware vendors. This software is open-source and licensed under the GNU GPLv3. The Phoronix Test Suite consists of a lightweight processing core (pts-core) with each benchmark consisting of an XML-based profile with related resource scripts. The process from the benchmark installation, to the actual benchmarking, to the parsing of important hardware and software components is heavily automated and completely repeatable, asking users only for confirmation of actions.

- 100+ Test Profiles
- 40+ Test Suites
- Extensible (XML-based) Testing Architecture
- Optional Linux-based LiveDVD/USB Testing Distribution (PTS Desktop Live)
- Automated Test Installation
- Dependency Management Support
- Module-based Plug-In Architecture
- Integrated Results Viewer
- PNG, JPG, Adobe SWF, SVG Graph Rendering Support
- Autonomous Batch Mode Support
- Global Database For Result Uploads, Benchmark Comparisons
- HTML Documentation Covering Test Profiles, Module Framework
- Installed Software, Hardware Detection
- System Monitoring Support
- Runs On Linux, OpenSolaris, Mac OS X, & BSD Operating Systems